# How to configure route between tun0 to access local machine?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iproute2

I have the following structure. All machines are Linux based.

```
Server                                     
------------------------
eth0 WAN                                   
tun0 192.168.2.1 peer 192.168.2.2/32 <-.
                                       |
Client                                 | (tun0)
------------------------               |
tun0 192.168.2.6 peer 192.168.2.5/32 <-'
eth3 LAN 192.168.0.0/24 <--------------.
                                       |
Device                                 | (lan)
------------------------               |
eth0 LAN 192.168.1.42/16 <-------------'
```

A VPN connection link the **Server** and the **Client**.

My goal is to access the local **Client** network (device) from the server. Here below the details about the Server and the **Client**.

From what I understood, as I would like to reach `192.168.0.0/24` from the **Server**, I need to route `192.168.0.0/24 via tun0`. So I tried to add a route with:

```
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev tun0
```

I also tried to route via `192.168.2.1`:

```
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.2.1
```

However, I am certainly missing something because it doesn't quite work yet. When I `tcpdump -n -i tun0` on the server, trying to reach a local address on the client with `ping 192.168.1.10` I can see the packets. But the same `tcpdump` command on the client doesn't show any packets. It seems the packets are lost somewhere in the tunnel.

Any hint?

### Server

```
$ ip a show tun0
50289: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 
qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 192.168.2.1 peer 192.168.2.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4df5:2cae:8c14:2279/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip r
default via 142.x.x.1 dev eth0 onlink
142.x.x.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 142.x.x.x
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.2 dev tun0
192.168.2.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
```

### Client

```
$ ip a s tun0
36: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast 
state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 192.168.2.6 peer 192.168.2.5/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev ovs_eth3  src 192.168.1.20
142.93.x.x via 192.168.1.1 dev ovs_eth3  src 192.168.1.20
192.168.1.0/24 dev ovs_eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.20
192.168.2.1 via 192.168.2.5 dev tun0
192.168.2.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.6

$ ip n
192.168.1.2 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr ec:b5:fa:09:07:ac STALE
192.168.1.4 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr 3c:6a:9d:13:d1:f2 STALE
192.168.1.9 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr 5c:ea:1d:74:fa:bb STALE
...
192.168.1.18 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr 02:11:32:20:17:25 REACHABLE
172.17.0.3 dev docker0 lladdr 02:42:ac:11:00:03 STALE
...
172.17.0.5 dev docker0 lladdr 02:42:ac:11:00:05 STALE
```

Comment: Do the devices in .0.0/24 have a route in the opposite direction?

Comment: Probably not. I should perhaps try to add one